# Zip Deployment of C# Console Application with Terraform into Azure Functions

Tags: .net, azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to do a zip deployment of a dotnet console application with Terraform into Azure Functions. With the current `main.tf` file I have, I am able to construct the infrastructure properly, but I am not able to deploy the code itself.

The following is the main.tf file I have:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.50"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">=1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-resource-group"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "azurerm_service_plan" {
  name                = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-app-service-plan"
  location            = var.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "application_insights" {
  name                = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-application-insights"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  application_type    = "other"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                     = "mttagsstorageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage_container" {
  name                  = "$web"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.storage_account
  ]
}

data "archive_file" "file_function_app" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = var.archive_location
  output_path = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-function-app.zip"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob" {
  name                   = "${filesha256(data.archive_file.file_function_app.output_path)}.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.storage_container.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = data.archive_file.file_function_app.output_path
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.storage_container,
    data.archive_file.file_function_app
  ]
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "storage_account_blob_container_sas" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.storage_container.name

  start  = "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  expiry = "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z"

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = false
    create = false
    write  = false
    delete = false
    list   = false
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_blob.storage_blob
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "manicTimeTagImporterFunctionApp" {
  name                = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-function-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_blob.storage_blob
  ]

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.azurerm_service_plan.id

  site_config {
    always_on = false
  }

  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME       = "dotnet"
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSIONS_VERSION   = "~3"
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE       = "https://${azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.storage_container.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.storage_blob.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.storage_account_blob_container_sas.sas}",
    AzureWebJobsStorage            = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_connection_string
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = azurerm_application_insights.application_insights.instrumentation_key
  }
}
```

I verified that the code is being correctly uploaded to the blob storage through the portal. But when I navigate to the HttpTrigger api link, I get a 404 not found error. I also don't see the function being called at all in the portal, and I have nothing in the log stream in the portal.

I don't know what exactly I am not doing right, please help! Happy to provide any other info if required.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment method you are trying to use is not "zip deploy" but rather "External package URL". See here for the comparison of various deployment models: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies

One thing that is missing is the Function App restart. If the URL to the package does not change, you need to ensure that the Function service is restarted after deployment. There are also other methods described in the MS article that will synchronize function triggers after the deployment of the code package.

You also mention that the application is dotnet console application, which is quite confusing. Maybe you can post the actual function declaration to validate that it is correctly defined and called.